# Limit of the integral of $x^n(1-k^{-1}x)^k$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

The following problem is problem #30 from Folland's Real Analysis.

Show that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\int_{0}^{k}x^{n}\left(1 - {x \over k}\right)^{k}\,{\rm d}x
=
n!
$$.

I need some help help on how to tackle this problem. Thank you!

Comment: The [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is hiding somewhere.

Comment: thnx for the correction

Comment: The [Beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) might prove itself useful: $$\int_0^1x^n(1-x)^mdx=B(m+1,n+1)=\frac{m!\cdot n!}{(m+n+1)!}$$

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large\left(1 - {x \over k}\right)^{k} \sim {\rm e}^{-x}\quad\mbox{when}\quad k \gg 1}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Write $f_k(x) = \chi_{[0,k]}(x) \cdot x^n (1-k^{-1} x)^k $ and remember that $1-\theta \leq e^{-\theta}$ for each $\theta\in {\mathbb R}$, use this to bound $f_k(x)$.  Finally, what is $\lim_k f_k(x)$ pointwise ? What convergence Theorem can you use now to exchange integral and limit?

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding rigor, we have:

$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} (1-\frac{x}{k})^k =e^{-x}$

So the integral goes to:

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^n e^{-x} = n!$

I hope someone can give a more rigorous solution.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Lucian (who gave the key), replace "x" by "k y". So, the result of the integration is just k^(n+1) B[k+1,n+1] and when "k" goes to infinity, the result is just n!

The question is however : are you supposed to know the Beta function ?